# Issue on Adding Animation to Bootstrap Navbar Affix

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

As you can see in [This Demo](http://www.bootply.com/kcljZGrNyL) I am trying to add affix functionality into the Bootstrap Navbar, but the affix pops up all the sudden on the page so I would like to add some animation into the affix. I tried to do this through CSS easing like

```
.navbar{
-webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750); 
-moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750); 
-o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750); 
 transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750); /* linear */    
}
```

but this is not doing the job! can you please let me know how I can add some animation to affix?

Comment: What are you attempting to make the navbar do on scroll? You should post any code you have or have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

First you should add a bigger top offset so the animation won't trigger almost at the begining and you can apreciate it.

If you want the navbar to do some animation to slide in when it turns into affix on scroll your css should be applied to `.affix` or `.navbar.affix` not the navbar in general.

I don't understand much of cubic-beizer so i changed the animation for the example. [Here is a demo](http://www.bootply.com/TytCh3BvU1).